# Creating second Stack Exchange account with same email address?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I want to have a second account to separate private and work-related activities.

Is that possible with only one mail address?

I tried but it only let me recover my password, not create a new account.

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: Work - use work address, Personal - use personal address.

Comment: Note: If you have a gmail account with name1.name2@gmail.com , you will be able to use name1name2@gmail.com, nam.e.1.name2@gmail.com and so on. They will look differently externally, but it will be considered the same for the google.

Answer (score 11):

No, it is not possible. Our account system is built on the premise of only one account ever existing per email address - they are meant to be unique. You could theoretically bypass this by using `+something` style additions onto the email address, which most popular services support. But we would not recommend doing so, as it can make the accounts even more difficult to manage.

Keep in mind we have automated merge systems that will merge your two accoumts together if you ever verify both emails to the same account - so be extremely careful if you try to do this. We do not officially support users operating multiple accounts at once and will not provide support for users who accidentally trigger such a merge - it cannot be undone.